# Evince produces segmentation fault

Tags: evince, segmentation-fault

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 on my laptop (Dell Precision M4700, 16GB RAM), it's quite pure at the moment. The problem is that Evince 3.30.0 produces segmentation fault (core dumped) on launch. It is happening since the system was installed and purging and reinstalling (through Synaptic as well) did not help. Any ideas how to make it work?

I entered

```
~/.local/share/gnome-shell
```

to check what is in the extensions folder - it happens, there is no such folder (no folders at all), 'ls' in /gnome-shell produces:

```
application_state
```

Swapping to another (freshly made) user and running Evince there produces the same result.

Running sudo debsums -s provided output:

```
debsums: changed file /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl (from xkb-data package)
```

which is a file I have edited manually. Having it replaced by the original file (and deleting that new user I made) I got some more output from running evince in terminal:

```
Attempting to read the recently used resources file at 
'/home/january/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed:
Failed to open file “/home/january/.local/share/recently-used.xbel”: 
Permission denied.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This file had permission to read and write for my user, but had no permissions for my group. I edited these permission to provide my group with read an write and now  it's just `Segmentation fault` like before when I run Evince.

I purged Evince again also with Synaptic to install version `3.28.2-1` (through Synaptic). First of all I encountered an error when I used GUI `Apply` button when trying to install Evince again:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Unable to lock the download directory.
```

The error did not appear though when I selected `Edit->Apply Marked Changes`. Reinstallation still produces Seg.fault when running Evince.

Running `sudo evince` I get:

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

As things happen out of random sometimes I managed to get an error from evince in GUI (splash would you call it?), sorry for it being quite big I wanted to include all possible data.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcHk7.jpg

Running `fsck` in recovery root command line yielded no errors.

I did memtest a couple of days ago and then I did one after doing the `fsck`, receiving this result:

Older: https://i.stack.imgur.com/21wuL.jpg

Newer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J58Ob.jpg

Comment: Welcome! It would be very difficult to diagnose without some additional details, such as: the Ubuntu version, evince package version, the complete output prior to the crash, and any other possibly useful details.

Comment: Sadly, the only output I get is just the "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" no other information is provided.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, evince package is the one got from the Software Center (I believe the one I am getting also through apt-get is the same) - version 3.30.0.

Can't really give any more details just as they are not present.

Comment: Evince 3.30.0 doesn't appear to be the default version used in 18.04.1... oh, it's a snap package. Have you installed any fonts? Themes? In `terminal`, type `evince` and edit your question to include the error messages.

Comment: As I said, the only error message (through terminal, running evince in GUI produces nothing at all) is the Segmentation Fault. Regarding the fonts I doubt I have installed some of them manually. I installed TeXMaker as well as MikTex, these could bring in some more fonts; also I have edited a certain xkb file to change the layout of my keyboard slightly.

Comment: Older laptop? How much RAM? Where/how did you install the extra fonts? Have you tried removing them to see if it impacts Evince? Have you installed any GNOME extensions? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema Laptop is pretty beasty. It's Dell Precision M4700 with 16GB RAM. It's usually has minor issues regarding it's uncommon hardware but I previously had no problem using Evince on Fedora Workstation for quite some time. By the time I noticed Evince not running I believe the only apps I had installed were: TexMaker, MikTex, python libs with Spyder, GitKraken, pavucontrol. I am not quite amateur with Linuxes so I can't really tell what do you mean by GNOME extensions. About the fonts - how possibly could I remove them?

Comment: Since this problem has very little data to diagnose... let's eliminate the obvious first... create a new user called "Guest" (or whatever) and log out of your normal account, and into Guest. Does Evince work there?

Comment: ps: in your normal account, show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, and edit that output into your original question... not the comments, please.

Comment: Make sure to send comments to @heynnema, or I may miss them. I manually noticed that you tried my suggestions, it still fails, so it's a systemic problem. Uninstall Evince 3.30, and use Synaptic to install 3.28... I suspect it'll still fail, as per your previous statements, but at least we'll be working with a version from 18.04.1. If it still fails, boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and run memtest for at least one complete pass. Report back.

Comment: ps: in `terminal`, run `sudo debsums -s`. Look at any errors and report back. Edit the error list into your question.

Comment: @heynnema I have updated my question with more information after your suggestions. I will run memtest later today and update.

Comment: Delete the file `/home/january/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`. Retry evince. In Synaptic, check to make sure that there are no held packages (from the left panel), and then select "Fix broken packages" from the menus. You may have to select it more than once.

Comment: @heynnema I have just edited with a link to a bug report if you would like to see into it, for now I will try your suggestion

Comment: I've looked at your "crash report". It's a memory allocation error. How much memory do you have? Have you run memtest yet? Go ahead with the file delete and report back.

Comment: @Smoksul status please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

We've got a malloc error with Evince.

**Step #1:**

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition for errors...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Step #2:**

Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and run `memtest` for one complete pass.

**Update #1:**

Memtest showed a memory failure, as I suspected. Remove or replace some RAM sticks.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, I was very busy last days, the post got updated accordingly to your suggestions

Comment: @Smoksul as I had suspected, bad RAM. Remove or replace a RAM stick.

Comment: that's quite surprising. I am running all kind of software without any issues on Windows, on Fedora, never had a bluescreen nor anything of that sort. I will try to maybe remove some of the RAM sticks and look for the bad one (provided it's not a malfunction of them being combined) in the future. Could it lead to more damage if I did not remove/replace the RAM stick soon (if it is actually malfucntioning)?

Comment: If you've mixed and matched different RAM sticks, that could certainly lead to a memtest error. If you have 4 RAM sticks, you can remove 2 paired sticks, rerun memtest, and when you get a pass, retry evince. Memory normally needs to get RAM added/removed in pairs, for memory interleaving performance reasons. Hence the suggestion to remove 2 RAM sticks... but you have to look closely to make sure to remove the proper pairs. Don't wait to repair this. See `sudo lshw -c memory` for a clue. Report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 3):

Got the same error since yesterday on evince 3.28.4 (exactly as described), no memory faults, devs, check what were the mods since yesterday both on evince and 4.15.0-43-generic 64-bits.
Checked  /var/log/apt/history.log

and between the days evince was working and then not working I have:
[the content of this file](https://ajoliveira.com/tmp/apt-history-log.txt.xz) 
, no reference to evince:amd64 (3.28.4-0ubuntu1) or any of the installed libraries:
libevdocument3-4:amd64 (3.28.4-0ubuntu1), libgxps2:amd64 (0.3.0-2), libspectre1:amd64 (0.2.8-1), libevview3-3:amd64 (3.28.4-0ubuntu1)

No evidence of any changed dependencies as provided by the [output of ldd](https://ajoliveira.com/tmp/dep.txt.xz) command:

It thus seems that 3.28.4 is corrupted.

finally solved the problem with:

```
sudo snap install evince  # version 3.30.2
```

and had everything working, with some gtk warnings if I call evince from the command-line. There is a drawback, evince installed through cannot access /tmp and opening a pdf through Thunderbird or Firefox will fail. You will have to save it first.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/915712)

Comment: I already completed my answer.